# Remove matched item from list Python

Tags: python, list, aws-lambda, boto3

How to remove matched item from list? `<class 'list'>`

```py
snapshot_tag = [{'Key': 'Disaster_Recovery', 'Value': 'Full'}, {'Key': 'Backup Initiator Rule', 'Value': 'Daily-6d-retention'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'HOSTNAME'}, {'Key': 'aws:backup:source-resource', 'Value': '000AD618-2D20-CE4B-0000-0000B688C579'}, {'Key': 'Backup_Type', 'Value': 'CROSS-REGION'}]
```

I need to remove an element:

```
{'Key': 'aws:backup:source-resource', 'Value': '000AD618-2D20-CE4B-0000-0000B688C579'}
```

I can remove it if specify full element name:

```
snapshot_tag.remove({'Key': 'aws:backup:source-resource', 'Value': '000AD618-2D20-CE4B-0000-0000B688C579'})
```

or specify a specific index:

`del snapshot_tag[3]`

but in my case 'Value' of an element always different and the index goes random.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use list comprehension:

```
print ([item for item in snapshot_tag if item['Key'] !=  'aws:backup:source-resource'])
```

or use filter,lambda:

```
print (list(filter(lambda item: item['Key'] != 'aws:backup:source-resource', snapshot_tag)))
```

output:

```
[{'Key': 'Disaster_Recovery', 'Value': 'Full'}, {'Key': 'Backup Initiator Rule', 'Value': 'Daily-6d-retention'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'HOSTNAME'}, {'Key': 'Backup_Type', 'Value': 'CROSS-REGION'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension:

```py
some_value = '000AD618-2D20-CE4B-0000-0000B688C579'

snapshot_tag = [s for s in snapshot_tag if s != {'Key': 'aws:backup:source-resource', 'Value': some_value}]
```

The `if` statement at the end will skip that element. Alternatively, you could use `filter`:

```py
a = list(filter(lambda x: x.get('Value') != '000AD618-2D20-CE4B-0000-0000B688C579', snapshot_tag))
```